How does mass-energy equivalence work with chemical bonds?
If you have, for instance, 2 oxygen atoms and do E=mc2 to get their equivalent energy, you get about 2.38nJ. However, if you have diatomic oxygen, there's also the energy of the bond; about 0.8aJ. Nonetheless, if you measure the masses of oxygen and diatomic oxygen separately, they would weigh the same, but would have a different energy. How does this agree with Einstein's equation?

The difference in energy is very small, and the correction to the mass is negligible for most practical purposes.

Does this answer your question? Conversion of mass to energy in chemical/nuclear reactions
